# jQuery validation works only on every other submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Checkbox List Validation Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#formUpdate").validate({
            rules: Object.assign({
                // TODO: validation rules?
            },
                messages: {
                // TODO: vaidation messages?
            }, mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules)
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body class="colorschemeBackground">
    <form id="formUpdate">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" class="colorschemeHeader">Pick a box. Its contents will help you on your way.&nbsp;<label id="Notes8Length"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" class="colorschemeBackground">
                    <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~1" id="Notes8~1" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Box 1<br>
                    <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~2" id="Notes8~2" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Box 2<br>
                    <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~3" id="Notes8~3" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Box 3<br>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        jQuery(function ($) {
                            function validateMultiple(selector, n, isExactlyN) {
                                const totChecked = $(selector).filter(':checked').length;
                                return isExactlyN ? totChecked == n : totChecked >= n;
                            }

                            var valid8 = true;
                            jQuery.validator.addMethod('Notes8',
                                function (value, element) {
                                    if (!valid8) return true; // only one error message per multilist
                                    valid8 = validateMultiple('.Notes8', 1);
                                    return valid8;
                                },
                                'Please check at least one check box.');
                        });
                        jQuery('form').validate();

                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" class="colorschemeHeader">What does the magic 8 ball say?&nbsp;<label id="Notes9Length"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" class="colorschemeBackground">
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~1" id="Notes9~1" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~2" id="Notes9~2" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~3" id="Notes9~3" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Maybe<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~4" id="Notes9~4" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;I don't know<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~5" id="Notes9~5" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Can you repeat the question?<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~6" id="Notes9~6" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;You're not the boss of me now!<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~7" id="Notes9~7" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;And you're not so big!<br>
                    <input class="Notes9" name="Notes9~8" id="Notes9~8" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Life is unfair...<br>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        jQuery(function ($) {
                            function validateMultiple(selector, n, isExactlyN) {
                                const totChecked = $(selector).filter(':checked').length;
                                return isExactlyN ? totChecked == n : totChecked >= n;
                            }

                            var valid9 = true;
                            jQuery.validator.addMethod('Notes9',
                                function (value, element) {
                                    if (!valid9) return true; // only one error message per multilist
                                    valid9 = validateMultiple('.Notes9', 1);
                                    return valid9;
                                },
                                'Please check at least one check box.');
                        });
                        jQuery('form').validate();

                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have two checkbox lists, Notes8 and Notes9, each with its own CSS class. I want the user to be required to check at least one check box from each list. When I initially submit the form with no check boxes checked, I get the intended error messages. However if I submit again without checking any boxes, it goes through without an error! Then it does so every other time I submit - error, goes through, error, goes through, etc. Refreshing the page resets the cycle.

Yes, I know the validation code is duplicated; it's dynamically generated code and placing the functions in the right place on the page would be tricky...

How can I get the validation code to work every time I submit the form, rather than just every other time?

Comment: Not necessarily related to the problem, but be aware that jQuery 1.4.4 is over 10 years out of date. You *really* need to upgrade it to 3.4.1. I'd also suggest you check that the version of validate.js you're using is recent too.

Comment: Why are you calling `jQuery('form').validate()` multiple times? You should call it once with all the validation options you want.

Comment: You have the call `jQuery("#formUpdate").validate()` before the form is defined. You have to put that code at the bottom or put it inside `jQuery(document).ready()`.

Comment: Yeah, this an old app, at least 10 years old. I would upgrade jQuery but I'm not all that familiar with it or the app so I don't want to break anything.

Comment: I'm calling `validate` multiple times because the validation code is generated by VB code and I have yet to figure out how to get it to only generate the `validate` call only once for the entire page.

Comment: I never had any trouble with the other `validate` call being up at the top of the page. There are other pages where we have actual validation rules and they seem to work just fine.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. It looks like the values of my `valid8` and `valid9` variables are persisted across submits to the page. I wonder why this is happening and how I can prevent it?